# Access Mongodb's Object with Mongodb ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/quick-start/#query-the-collection
I'm following this tutorial, i'm trying to query an existing database that is hosted in mongodb atlas

It seems like when i put

```
puts client[:videos].find( { id: '1234' } )
```

It simply just return

```
#<Mongo::Collection::View:0x00007fee25ad3e08>
```

This doesnt work as well

```
client[:videos].find( { id: '1234' } ).title
```

it won't return the value within the db field, anything i'm missing?

I don't want to use Mongoid ODM because the model was constructed by another language, i was just trying to do some quick query

Answer (score 0):

```
puts client[:videos].find( { id: '1234' } ).first
```

i figured out, i'm suppose to put .first at the end